# OpenBUGS example: Stagnant, a changepoint problem and an illustration of how NOT to do MCMC! - Why is the second parameterization better?

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, change-point, bugs

I am working on an Bayesian problem from an [OpenBugs example: Stagnant, a changepoint problem and an illustration of how NOT to do MCMC!](http://www.openbugs.net/Examples/Stagnant.html). This is a changepoint problem. Basically we assume a model with two straight lines that meet at a certain changepoint $x_k$.

The raw data looks like the following.

[image]

The basic setup is as following. (I am using $\sigma^2$ instead of precision $\tau$ as in the original example.)
\begin{align*}
Y_i \ & \sim \ N(\alpha + \beta_1 (x_i - x_k), \sigma^2), \; i = 1, \ldots, k \\
Y_i \ & \sim \ N(\alpha + \beta_2 (x_i - x_k), \sigma^2), \; i = k+1, \ldots, n \\
\end{align*}

Based on above plot, we might expect that $\beta_2$ is smaller than $\beta_1$ - deeper drop at later part, and the changepoint $x_k$ is around 0.

The example illustrates two parameterizations in terms of modeling the changepoint.

---

**The first way is to assume the changepoint index $k$ a discrete uniform**. The priors are
\begin{align*}
\alpha \ & \sim \ N(\mu_{\alpha}, \sigma^2_{\alpha}), \quad \sigma^2 \ \sim \ IG(a, b) \\
\beta_1, \beta_2 \ & \sim \ N(\mu_{\beta}, \sigma^2_{\beta}), \quad k \ \sim \ Unif\{1, n\}
\end{align*}
That is, the changepoint value $x_k$ is constrained to be one observed $x$ value.

The example points out one issue as following.

> Note: alpha is E(Y) at the changepoint, so will be highly correlated with k. This may be a very poor parameterisation.

And as demonstrated in the example, "**Results are hopeless - no mixing at all**", and highly depend on the initial values of parameters (**chain 1 (red)**: alpha = 0.2, k = 16; **chain 2 (blue)**: alpha = 0.6, k = 8).

[image]

[image]

---

**The second way is, instead of putting distribution on $k$, assuming the changepoint value $x_k$ a continuous uniform.** Priors for other parameters are the same.
\begin{align*}
x_k \ \sim \ Unif(x_l, x_u)
\end{align*}
where $x_l, x_u$ can be predefined based on the range of observed $x$'s. In the example, $x_l=-1.3, x_u = 1.1$.

The results now did get better, as shown in following.
[image]
[image]

---

**To fully understand this example, I have following questions.**

1. Why does the second parameterization work better? I assume that there is still "high correlation" issue (between $x_k$ and $\alpha$, as opposed to $k$ and $\alpha$ in first approach). The example shows the correlation between $x_k$ and $\alpha$ is **-0.932941**. So if the "high correlation" issue is not fixed, what does make the second way better?
2. What is the main point of this example? What does the title mean by saying "**illustration of how NOT to do MCMC**"?
3. In this particular example, are there even better parameterization approaches?

   Thank you very much for any comments.